# MissingMethodException DbSet.ToList

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core

On my Entity Framework Core project I've a generic repository with a `GetAll()` method

```
public ICollection<Entity> GetAll(){
    return DbSet.ToList();
}
```

But when I execute it, throws the following:

```
System.MissingMethodException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233069
  Message=Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryContextFactory..ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IStateManager, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.IConcurrencyDetector, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IChangeDetector)'.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalQueryContextFactory..ctor(IStateManager stateManager, IConcurrencyDetector concurrencyDetector, IRelationalConnection connection, IChangeDetector changeDetector)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c.<AddQuery>b__1_1(IServiceProvider p)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_QueryProvider()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.<.ctor>b__3_0()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TEntity>.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at DataAccessLayer.Repositories.BaseRepository`1.GetAll() in D:\TFS-LocalVersions\tourstop\Service\Musical.Broccoli.API\src\DataAccessLayer\Repositories\BaseRepository.cs:line 30
       at Testing.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\TFS-LocalVersions\tourstop\Service\Musical.Broccoli.API\Testing\Program.cs:line 40
  InnerException
```

The `DbContext` is being inject and I can add registries, but cannot do a ToList().

My `DbContext` is

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<Entity> Addresses { get; set; }
```

The repository constructor:

```
public BaseRepository(Context context)
    {
        this.Context = context;
        this.DbSet = this.Context.Set<Entity>();
    }
```

And is being injected with the default DI

The project.json is the following:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore": "7.0.6-IR31",
    "MySql.Data": "7.0.6-IR31",
    "Common": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Does someone has any ideas on why, and how to solve it?

Comment: You should display more code from your repository - we don't know what `DbSet` is!  I'm doing a lot of assuming in my answer below (maybe I shouldn't have answered), but, hopefully helpful still.

Comment: Sorry, just updated the question

Comment: Also, how are you implementing the base repository?

Comment: Simple inheritance and constructor override

Comment: Are you remembering to call base on your derived repo? 
`public SomeRepository(SomeContext context) : base(context) { }`  the `context.Set<T>.ToList()` should work just fine.

Comment: Of course, as I said I can add registries.

Comment: You are likely mixing package versions

Comment: I'll post the project.json

Comment: Hi, I ran into the exact same error, and was able to resolve it using the answer. I'm upgrading to 1.1 also, but I have this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881807/connectionstring-not-read-properly-ef-core. Did you by any chance run into this? If not, can you post how you pass in the connection string to help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0"
from project.json

Comment: This wouldn't have crossed my mind ever, but it works. If you could explain why, for further reference, it would be appreciated.

Comment: This issue is dependency injection. [MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore/7.0.6-IR31) already depend on ef.core and probably installs another version of EF.Core. Search the project.json.lock file for EntityFrameworkCore now after you've removed it and you'll see that it's still there, but it's not 1.1.0. At least this was the case for me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a context that looks something like the following:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
        : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<SomeEntity> SomeEntities { get; set; }
    ...
```

Your access to those entities through a generic repository would look something like this (where `T` is `SomeEntity`):

```
public IList<T> GetAll()
{
    return MyContext.Set<T>.ToList();
}
```

You probably want to go through this tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro) to understand more about Entity Framework Core's DbContext and accessing your entities through it.