# ConnectionString not read properly - EF Core

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core to connect to a MySQL database. Ever since upgrading from 1.0 to 1.1, my connection string does not seem to be read properly. Here is my project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "MySql.Data": "7.0.6-IR31",
    "MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore": "7.0.6-IR31",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-*"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm initialising a DBContext like this:

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Entities>();
optionsBuilder.UseMySQL(TestSettings.ConnectionString);

// Ensure database creation
context = new Entities(optionsBuilder.Options);
```

It seems to substitute some default value for the host name:

```
Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
One or more errors occurred. (The requested address is not valid in its context 255.255.255.255:3306)

The requested address is not valid in its context 255.255.255.255:3306
```

This is the connection string:

```
"server=mmocstagingdb.australiasoutheast.cloudapp.azure.com;user id=root;password=root;database=root;Convert Zero Datetime=True;SSL Mode=None"
```

(Username, password, and database values are substituted) For what it's worth, `TestSettings` is a static class with a static field `ConnectionString`

Anyone have any ideas?

P.S.

I think this question is somewhat related: [MissingMethodException DbSet.ToList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729718/missingmethodexception-dbset-tolist)

I have updated to .NET Core 1.1 lately and ran into the same error as the mentioned post. I resolved it using the accepted answer. But now running into this problem.

Comment: Can you post the connection string?

Comment: @J.Pichardo Posted. please see edit

Comment: @l3utterfly Maybe your server requires `SSL`. Did you try this?

Comment: @I3utterfly Have you tried changing `user id=root` for `userid=root`?

Comment: Ok, ok, this is very embarrassing... see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embarrassing answer here, but posting in case someone else runs into this cryptic error message.

It turns out the host was inaccessible because I stopped the server on Azure before and forgot.

But apparently, if the host is inaccessible, the will show it trying to connect to 255.255.255.255:3306... which lead me down the wrong train of thought thinking the connection string was not passed in correctly.